# Stripe functions returning calls after function finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

Relatively new to Javascript however, i'm trying to work with Stripe and my way around a user submitting another payment method and then paying an invoice with that method. if the payment fails again - it should remove the subscription alltogether.  I'm using Firebase Realtime Database with GCF & Node.js 8.

Here is what i have so far

```
exports.onSecondPaymentAttempt = functions.database.ref("users/{userId}/something/somethingHistory/{subDbId}/newPayment").onCreate((snapshot, context)=>{
var s = snapshot.val();
var fields = s.split(",");
const cardToken = fields[0];
const cus_id = fields[1];
const conn_id = fields[2];
const subDbId = context.params.subDbId;
const userId = context.params.userId;
return stripe.customers.createSource(
    cus_id,
    {source: cardToken},{
        stripeAccount: `${conn_id}`,
      },
  (err, card)=> {
    console.log(err); 
    if(err){
        return console.log("error attaching card "+ err)
    }else{
        const invoiceNo = admin.database().ref(`users/${userId}/something/somethingHistory/${subDbId}`)
        return invoiceNo.once('value').then(snapshot=>{
        const invoiceNumber = snapshot.child("invoiceId").val();
        const subId = snapshot.child("subscriptionId").val();
        return stripe.invoices.pay(
        invoiceNumber,
        {
      expand: ['payment_intent','charge','subscription'],
        },{
            stripeAccount: `${conn_id}`,
          },
          (err, invoice)=>{
              if(err){
                return console.log("error paying invoice "+ err)
              }else{
                if(invoice.payment_intent.status==="succeeded"){
              //DO SOME CODE
                return console.log("New Payment succeeded for "+invoiceNumber)
            }else{
             //DO SOME OTHER CODE

            //CANCEL 
            return stripe.subscriptions.del(
                subId,{
            stripeAccount: `${conn_id}`,
             },
            (err, confirmation)=> {
                if(err){
                    return console.log("Subscription error")
                }else{
                         return console.log("Subscription cancelled")
                }
             });
              }
              }
          });
})
    }
});
```

To me it looks like an incredibly inefficient / ugly way of achieving the effect and overall the user is sitting waiting for a response for approx 15 seconds although the function finishes its execution after 1862ms - I still get responses up to 5 - 10 seconds after.

What's the most efficient way of achieving the same desired effect of registering a new payment source, paying subscription and then handling the result of that payment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Promises returned by the Stripe asynchronous methods, as follows (untested, it probably needs some fine tuning, in particular with the objects passed to the Stripe methods):

```
exports.onSecondPaymentAttempt = functions.database.ref("users/{userId}/something/somethingHistory/{subDbId}/newPayment").onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    var s = snapshot.val();
    var fields = s.split(",");
    const cardToken = fields[0];
    const cus_id = fields[1];
    const conn_id = fields[2];
    const subDbId = context.params.subDbId;
    const userId = context.params.userId;


    return stripe.customers.createSource(
        //Format of this object to be confirmed....
        cus_id,
        { source: cardToken },
        { stripeAccount: `${conn_id}` }
    )
        .then(card => {
            const invoiceNo = admin.database().ref(`users/${userId}/something/somethingHistory/${subDbId}`)
            return invoiceNo.once('value')
        })
        .then(snapshot => {
            const invoiceNumber = snapshot.child("invoiceId").val();
            const subId = snapshot.child("subscriptionId").val();
            return stripe.invoices.pay(
                invoiceNumber,
                { expand: ['payment_intent', 'charge', 'subscription'] },
                { stripeAccount: `${conn_id}` }
            )
        })
        .then(invoice => {

            if (invoice.payment_intent.status === "succeeded") {
                //DO SOME CODE
                console.log("New Payment succeeded for " + invoiceNumber)
                return null;
            } else {
                //DO SOME OTHER CODE

                //CANCEL 
                return stripe.subscriptions.del(
                    subId, {
                    stripeAccount: `${conn_id}`,
                });
            }

        })
        .catch(err => {
            //....
            return null;
        })

});
```

---

I would suggest you watch the three videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the official [Firebase video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/), which explain why it is key to correctly [chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) and return the promises returned by the asynchronous methods.

Comment: @JamesPalfrey Hello, did you have the opportunity to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Hey, i did, thanks very much, i actually ended up looking through a udemy course / the Firebase video series you suggested and muddled my way to a solution, so i've marked your answer as correct :) thanks.